# How to create a Python GTK3 TreeView column which contains BOTH text and images

Tags: python, treeview, gtk3

I have a GTK3 Python program with a TreeView, and I would like to have a column that mostly contains text, but can also contain an image. I've been asking ChatGPT, but this is as close as I can get:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

class TreeViewExample(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="TreeView Table Example")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # Create a ListStore model with two columns
        self.model = Gtk.ListStore(object, str)  # Using 'object' type for the first column
        self.model.append([self.load_image("path/to/your/image.png"), "Value A"])  # First row with an image
        self.model.append(["Row 2", "Value B"])  # Second row with text
        self.model.append(["Row 3", "Value C"])

        # Create a TreeView
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.model)

        # Create the first column with custom cell renderers
        column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 1")
        self.treeview.append_column(column1)

        # Create a text renderer for the first column
        cell_renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column1.pack_start(cell_renderer_text, expand=True)
        column1.add_attribute(cell_renderer_text, "text", 1)  # Display text
        column1.set_cell_data_func(cell_renderer_text, self.render_first_column)  # Custom rendering function

        # Create an image renderer for the first column
        cell_renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        column1.pack_start(cell_renderer_pixbuf, expand=True)
        column1.add_attribute(cell_renderer_pixbuf, "pixbuf", 0)  # Display image

        # Create the second column with a text renderer
        cell_renderer2 = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 2", cell_renderer2, text=1)
        self.treeview.append_column(column2)

        # Add the TreeView to the window
        self.add(self.treeview)

    def load_image(self, image_path):
        # Load an image from file and return a GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf
        try:
            pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(image_path)
            return pixbuf
        except GLib.Error:
            print(f"Error loading image from {image_path}")
            return None

    def render_first_column(self, column, cell, model, iter_, data=None):
        # Custom rendering function for the first column
        value = model.get_value(iter_, 0)
        if isinstance(value, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf):
            cell.set_property("pixbuf", value)  # Display the image
        else:
            cell.set_property("text", str(value))  # Display text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TreeViewExample()
    app.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    app.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

It seems right that the first model column is an "object" so it can either be a str or a pixbuf. But the call to set_cell_data_func has a parameter of cell_renderer_text, so when the self.render_first_column function is called, the cell parameter always seems to be a CellRendererText, so when the value is a pixbuf and it runs the command:

```
cell.set_property("pixbuf", value)
```

If fails with:

```
builtins.TypeError: object of type `GtkCellRendererText' does not have property `pixbuf'
```

This post ([How to make a column with a string and pixbuf in GtkTreeview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648323/how-to-make-a-column-with-a-string-and-pixbuf-in-gtktreeview)) seems to put both of the CellRenderers together without using a cell_data_func, but my attempts along those lines haven't been successful either.

Can someone help me turn this into working code?

I would also appreciate some help understanding the column.pack_start and column.add_attribute methods. It seems like the pack_start method is for having multiple CellRenderers in the same cell, but how does it know which one to use?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use pack_start to get two columns of data from the model presented in the same column, but it doesn't put them in the same position - the first item appears to the left and the second item appears to the right (sort of like two columns within the column). This is how this appears:

[image]

That's not very helpful... I want the image to appear in the same position as the text in the other rows.

Here is the code which produces this output (you have to supply an appropriate image):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

class TreeViewExample(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="TreeView Table Example")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # Create a ListStore model with two columns
        self.model = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)  # Using 'object' type for the first column
        self.model.append(["", "Value A", self.load_image("mypic.png")])  # First row with an image
        self.model.append(["Row 2", "Value B", None])
        self.model.append(["Row 3", "Value C", None])

        # Create a TreeView
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.model)

        # Create the first column
        column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 1")
        self.treeview.append_column(column1)
        
        cell_renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        column1.pack_start(cell_renderer_pixbuf, expand=True);
        column1.add_attribute(cell_renderer_pixbuf, "pixbuf", 2);

        cell_renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column1.pack_start(cell_renderer_text, expand=True);
        column1.add_attribute(cell_renderer_text, "text", 0);

        # Create the second column with another text renderer
        cell_renderer2 = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 2", cell_renderer2, text=1)
        self.treeview.append_column(column2)

        # Add the TreeView to the window
        self.add(self.treeview)

    def load_image(self, image_path):
        # Load an image from file and return a GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf
        try:
            pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(image_path)
            return pixbuf
        except GLib.Error:
            print(f"Error loading image from {image_path}")
            return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TreeViewExample()
    app.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    app.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

So I'm still looking for an answer, maybe one that can have an "object" in the model that can be either text or a pixbuf, and the TreeView will display whatever is in the model correctly.